# ldapsearch: Multiple identical pages when using paged search

Tags: ldap

I am running the following ldapsearch command on an eDirectory LDAP server that has paged search enabled:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -h server -p port -D admin -w password -b base -s sub "(&(objectclass=top)(objectclass=person)(and some additional object classes))" dn
```

The result is a number of pages which have identical contents. An example: My directory has 3500 objects that match the search filter. The default page size is 1000. So I expect 3 pages with 1000 different objects plus one final page that has the remaining 500 objects; four pages in total. The actual result, however, is in fact four pages, but all of them contain all of the 3500 objects. With either paging turned off or by not exceeding the page size, I get all objects in one step and without duplicates.

On a POSIX server I get some kind of a mixed result: ldapsearch works perfectly and returns the expected number of pages and objects. But when issuing the search using a client porgram written in C using the Windows LDAP API (ldap_search_init_page(), followed by multiple calls of ldap_get_next_page_s() until LDAP_NO_RESULTS_RETURNED is returned), I get duplicate pages like described above.

I haven’t yet observed this behavior in openLDAP and Oracle DSEE.

What can be the reason for those duplicate pages? How can I avoid them? Are there parameters to be set or taken into account other than supportedControl = 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 that indicates that paging is active?

Comment: What kind of "POSIX server" exactly? POSIX does not specify anything about LDAP. Are you referring to the ldapsearch command (which comes from OpenLDAP)?

Comment: And are you sure ldapsearch is actually using paged search mode? That feature is not active by default; the client needs to be configured to request it (e.g. using `-E pr=100`), otherwise it does a regular full search.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise. Furthermore, it seems that I received contradictory information on that server: That it is an Oracle Internet Directory based upon Posix. The latter seems to be wrong (?). But OID is correct.

We used the ldapsearch command provided by the LDAP server (same with the eDirectory problem: ldapsearch was carried out on the server). And we did use the -E pr=100 parameter to make sure do a paged search.

Comment: Try `-E pr=1000/noprompt`.

Comment: If there are more than 1000 objects, say, 1005, `-E pr=1000/noprompt` leads to two pages, each of them containing 1005 objects. The (no)prompt parameter is meaningless in this case.Note that this is the result on an eDirectory server. On OID, ldapsearch does the right thing; there it is the client call using the Windows LDAP API that behaves like ldapsearch does on eDirectory, i.e. returning multiple pages with same contents.